# How to use Active Directory (domain groups) for user management in SLURM?

Tags: centos, users, active-directory, domain, slurm

We have a GPU cluster (centOS 8) in our company network which runs SLURM.

Now we would like to realize the SLURM user management via our windows domain controller (active directory).

Every user which is part of a certain AD group should have access to SLURM.
SLURM should use the domain users.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Join the SLURM login node and/or compute nodes to AD and configure SSH to only permit "domain users" with `AllowGroups "domain users"`